# Allow zip function to map 1D to 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have these two arrays where one of them is 2D.

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
```

Now, I want to have the following assignment so that `letters` matches every list in the `values`, something like this:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4

a 10
b 20
c 30
d 40
```

The following code works only if both `letters` and `values` are `1D`. How can I fix it to achieve my desired assignment above?

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
for l, v in zip(letters, values):
    print(l,v)
```

Thank you

Comment: If memory / performance isn't a concern, you can use `for l, v in zip([letters]*len(values), values)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the data twice:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
for v in values:
  for a, b in zip(letters, v):
    print(f'{a} {b}')
  print()
```

Output:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4

a 10
b 20
c 30
d 40
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is useful to you to have tuples of the letters and the numbers they match, you might consider this:

```
for t in zip(letters, *values):
    print(t)
```

output:

```
('a', 1, 10)
('b', 2, 20)
('c', 3, 30)
('d', 4, 40)
```

If your goal is to associate the letters with each of the corresponding values from the value lists, this is faster than looping over `letters` once for each list in `values`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use zip twice:

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]
out = list(zip(letters, values[0])) + list(zip(letters, values[1]))
```

or for a more robust solution you could iterate through the lists in values

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
values = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 20, 30, 40]]

out = []
[out + list(zip(letters, v)) for v in values]
```

**Edit: Apologies, the accepted answer already does this.**